# Long boot time, Snap not working, Internet not working

Tags: internet, snap, apparmor, dmesg, boot-time

Some days ago, I powered on my *Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro* with *Ubuntu 22.04 LTS* and noticed a very long boot time (More than 150 seconds). After logging in, I noticed wifi was connected successfully but the internet was not working. It was the same with a wired connection.
After some moments, I realized snap apps are also not working at all.

Things I tried:

- `apt update`
- `apt upgrade`
- `snap refresh`

Logs:

- dmesg: [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/leyvifgw8ew9e2g/start%20log%20%283%29.txt?dl=0)

It seems there are some permission problems caused by AppArmor for snap apps, But I think it's not the root problem. Because the internet is also not working. I think there is a root problem that is the reason for all of these problems. Because, the day before, I haven't had any problem with my laptop and the only thing I did that day, was surfing the web. I think there is a bug in the recent automatic update by whether apt or snap.

Comment: @user535733 Because, the day before, I haven't had any problem with my laptop and the only thing I did that day, was surfing the web. I think there is a bug in the recent automatic update by whether apt or snap.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1420355/edit) to include your apt log to see what changed during that period. Also the complete output of `snap list`. Updates are commonly blamed but rarely the actual cause, so let's look there first.